# Apache not serve file after uploading

Tags: apache

I got this odd problem. When I uploaded folder **test** which contains **index.php** file in there, then access it via browser: **mydoamain.com/test/index.php**, then it shows file not found error.

However, if I create new directory called **test1**, make a new file **index.php** in there and copy all content in **test/index.php** into **test1/index.php** and save it. Then I can acess **mydomain.com/test1/index.php** normally.

same thing happened for other file types, meaning that I need to manually create new files and copy content from uploaded files into newly created files, deleted uploaded files and rename new file to match previous uploaded files.

Can you tell me what happened here?

Comment: my guess is apache is not realizing that you've uploaded these files (seems obvious) try restarting apache once file upload is complete and it should catch them

Comment: what are the permissions of the folder (test) when you upload it vs when you copy the files into a folder your created (test1)?

Comment: 0644 for files and 0755 for folder